# Sort spreadsheet values based on date column does not work - only sort alphabetically is offered

Tags: excel, date, sorting, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to sort the values in my spreadsheet based on the F column (date column), but I am not able to. In excel, the option "Sort by date" does not even appear. In google spreadsheet, this seems to be not possible either. My dates are under the form: 9/5/2022 where 9 is the day, 5 is the month (May) and 2022 is the year. It seems they only offer the option to sort alphabetically from A to Z but not by date.

How can I do this?

Here is a link to my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15RNXgcGn_ZR1iSnQ6o5IHAfdzq7__gyuzI-tNu4v188/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please, check https://spreadsheetpoint.com/sort-by-date-in-google-sheets/ section **Sort by Date Using the SORT Range Functionality**

Comment: The entries are not all dates.  Most likely you have imported from a CSV file with a date format of DMY, but the computer doing the import has windows settings of MDY.  As a consequence, all the dates where `d>12` will be imported as text, and, since your column is not entirely dates, you are not offered the option to sort oldest to newest.  Best fix would be to properly import the file (assuming that is the source of the error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71495339/sort-spreadsheet-values-based-on-date-column-does-not-work-only-sort-alphabeti#comment126367368_71495339), not all values in `F` are dates. That's most likely related to the fact that month and day are switched when compared to the values in `E`. Because of this, dates where day is higher than 12 are not valid (since there are only 12 months), and hence become text. And even in valid dates, the date in `F` and the "date" (actually text) in `E` have month and day switched up (e.g. 1 June becomes 6 January and vice versa).

I don't know how the dates in `F` were imported, but consider trying to do it again, taking into account this problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you have valid dates so try like this:

[image]